# JS Fetching batch data with HTTP

Tags: javascript, http, google-chrome-devtools, fetch-api

My RESTful service allows [batching requests](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/batch).

I'm trying to combine requests into one batch with help of [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API):

```js
let req1 = {
        url: "/cups/count",
        options: {
           method: 'GET',
           headers: {
               'Content-Type': 'application/http'
           }
       }
    },

    req2 = {
        url: "/spoons/count",
        options: {
           method: 'GET',
           headers: {
               'Content-Type': 'application/http'
           }
        }
    },
    authToken = "Bearer my_token123",
    batchUrl = "http://something.com/batch",
    options = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Authorization': authToken,
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/mixed'
        },
        body: {req1, req2}
    };

    return fetch(batchUrl, options)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(items => dispatch(batchSuccess(items)))
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err)
        });
```

However it returns an error - bad request. I suppose I may combine HTTP requests in wrong way.

Is there simpler way of doing this?

Where in Network Chrome Dev Tools can I see nested HTTP requests?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code does not work because it does not follow `multipart/mixed` request format:

1. In `Content-Type` header, there is no boundary information.
2. The child requests are not divided by boundary, instead they will be sent as plain text of req1 & req2 object.

In order to send valid `multipart/mixed` request, there is a node.js module [batchelor](https://www.npmjs.com/package/batchelor). According to the introduction page, its usage is pretty simple.

If you want to send `multipart/mixed` request from browser, you can use build tool (gulp, webpack etc.) to compile batchelor into something like "batchelor-compiled.js" and import it in HTML.

For developer tool, I didn't find anything in Chrome, but the child requests are visible in Firefox debug window's "Params" tab.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of a batch request using the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) with the [Gmail Batch REST API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/batch).

This will get the content of several messages at once.

```
const response = await fetch("https://www.googleapis.com/batch/gmail/v1", {
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "multipart/mixed; boundary=batch_boundary",
    Authorization: "Bearer <access_token>",
  },
  method: "POST",
  body: `--batch_boundary
Content-Type: application/http
Content-ID: 1

GET /gmail/v1/users/me/messages/{message-id-1}

--batch_boundary
Content-Type: application/http
Content-ID: 2

GET /gmail/v1/users/me/messages/{message-id-2}

--batch_boundary--`,
});

console.log(await response.text());
```

Comment: Just a small note that the Authorization header has a typo: it should be `Authorization: "Bearer <access_token>"`